# How to initialize a struct with enum member?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct with many members and with different types (it's like 20 members):

```
enum TheEnum
{
    FIRST = 0,
    SECOND,
    ...
}

struct TheStruct
{
    TheEnum z; // <--- the point !!! note that this is the first member (edited)
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[32];
    ...
}
```

Due to there is an enum type member, I  cant just declare like:

```
TheStruct Object = {0};
```

It will give compile error, but this initialization is the best way in my opinion.

The other ways that I can think of is:
1. `ZeroMemory` it, but I dont like this one. 
2. Write a constructor, but this needs a lot of work. 
3. Just don't initialize it.

So, is there any way to solve the **enum** problem? Should I pick a way in these 3?
Thanks!

EDIT:
My big mistake, the error only occurs when `TheEnum` presents as the first member.
Compiled using vs2008 and as C++ code.
The error is C2440. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: What is the compiler error? Compiles fine: http://ideone.com/1XVVWO

Comment: it worked on gcc 4.7.2, am I missing something?

Comment: I compiled using vs2008 and as C++ code.
The error is C2440.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Please give these crucial details in the question rather than in comments. Don't make us skull around the comments to find these details.

Comment: OK, I'll add to my post. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit] as the question changed

If you initialize a struct, you have to provide the correct types in your initializer.
In your case, the correct initialization would look like this:

```
TheStruct Object = {FIRST};
```

Your initialization list initializes the given number of struct members with what you have written and the rest of the struct with '0'.
Since your first member is an enum, you have to initialize that enum in this case.

[/edit]

there is nothing necessary. if you're compiling in C and not C++ just don't forget to write enum and struct and everything should work...

```
enum TheEnum
{
    FIRST = 0,
    SECOND,
    ...
}

struct TheStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[32];
    ...
    enum TheEnum z; // <--- the point !!!
}

struct TheStruct Object = {0};
```

Comment: You know what other language does not have this problem? C#. Maybe the OP should compile as C#.

Comment: since the code above compiles just fine in C++ (also see comment of hmjd), my guess is, he inadvertendly compiled it as C code...

Comment: I compiled using vs2008 and as C++ code.
The error is C2440.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: with the edit of your question, see my edited answer for the solution... ;-)

Comment: although not expected as my imagination, but this is no doubt a correct answer. accepted and upvoted :p

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the `enum` member just like any other. For example: `TheStruct temp = {0,0,"", FIRST};`

Comment: Hi I edited the problem...sorry the enum member should be the first member. And I do want to use the `= {0}` trick instead of write each member specifically because there are too many to write.

Comment: Everything that's not initialized explicitly will be initialized to 0. In your case `TheStruct temp = {FIRST};` will initialize the enum to `FIRST` and rest of the fields will be implicitly set to 0.

Comment: That could work, maybe I'll try it. But is there a more "general" way to do it? If someone changes the names in `TheEnum` then I have to modify this initialzation. And somehow my attempt is like to set everything to zero and regardless of what is in `TheEnum`.

Comment: The more general way is to define a constructor

Comment: as I said in my post...there are too many members. So u suggest no matter how many members there are, just init them all in ctor?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, I'm just presenting options. If you put your enum as a first field, you don't have to initialize rest of the fields, they will be default initialized to 0. Having a constructor you can extend this and give any default you want to other fields.

Comment: I know I only have to specified the first field. If my first field is `int` then I can use `={0}` trick, but now it's an enum, so it make me painful. Ctor is good, but the problem is that I'm having too many members to write down codes to init them.